# Error 403 Forbidden : Impossible to access to jcenter

Tags: android, gradle, jcenter

From this morning, gradle build failed due to error when accessing to jcenter :

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.koin:koin-android:2.2.1.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve org.koin:koin-android:2.2.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/koin/koin-android/2.2.1/koin-android-2.2.1.module'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/koin/koin-android/2.2.1/koin-android-2.2.1.module'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> > Could not resolve org.koin:koin-android:2.2.1.
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/koin/koin-android/2.2.1/koin-android-2.2.1.module'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/koin/koin-android/2.2.1/koin-android-2.2.1.module'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I saw Jcenter Maintenance last night (https://status.bintray.com/).
Does anyone else have this concern?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Jcenter()` with `MavenCentral()` in your Project level build.gradle file.
Eg:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral() }
```

// Jcenter() replaced